# TeamCity Configuration Can't Restore From TeamCity NuGet Feed

Tags: nuget, teamcity

I'm setting up some CI with build configurations that require some NuGet packages. These NuGet packages are built on the same server which is nice. I've read that I can use TeamCity's NuGet feed to meet my requirements. I've been following [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/using-teamcity-as-nuget-feed.html) guide.

I've created the feed on the `Build` project which has generated the `v1`, `v2`, and `v3` endpoints. For indexing packages, I've gone for the first option, namely

> To index packages published by the selected build configurations only, add the NuGet packages indexer build feature to these build configurations.

as it seemed to be the most straight forward. The `NuGet packages indexer` feature is applied to the two configurations that build NuGet package artifacts. These artifacts are building correctly as seen below:

[image]
If I plug the `v3` endpoing into Visual Studio `Package Sources` for example, I just get an authentication prompt followed by the error `Unable to load the service index for source .../v3/index.json. Response status code does not indicate success: 401 ().` If I paste the `v3` endpoint into a browser, I get a `json` object with a collection of objects with properties `@id`, `@type`, and `comment`. `v1` and `v2` in the browser show me an XML file with an empty `Packages` collection.

How do I confirm my packages actually ended up in the feed and/or am I misunderstanding how the endpoints are used?

**Update**: Turns out it was indeed a misunderstanding on my part. The /v3/index.json lists actions one can take on the feed. Using /v3/query lists all packages hosted by the feed.

The remaining problem is the error trying to consume packages from the feed. TeamCity throws the following errors:

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.201\NuGet.targets(124,5): error : Unable to load the service index for source <host>/httpAuth/app/nuget/feed/<project>/<feed_name>/v3/index.json
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.201\NuGet.targets(124,5): error :   Response status code does not indicate success: 401 ().
```

Alongside the solution file in my vault is the following `NuGet.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
     <add key="nugetserver" value="<host>/httpAuth/app/nuget/feed/<project>/<feed_name>/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

Is something else required to connect all the dots?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out TeamCity has a neat little feature where it can pretty easily reference a TeamCity feed within the `NuGet Installer` runner type as a build step by placing the feed into the `Packages sources` input. By executing this build step before the one that `publishes` my files, all is well.